# Using DisplayAttribute of column in a Controller

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, displayattribute

I have defined `[Display(Name = "From Date")]` for columns in a Model and I am using it from a View with the help of tag helpers like `asp-for` and `@Html.DisplayNameFor()`.

But I am exporting data to an Excel sheet, and that code is in a controller. Now to set the column header in excel I want to take column names from `[Display(Name = "From Date")]` instead of hard coding it.
How can I use it?

To make my point more clear, my existing code is:

```cs
row.CreateCell(1).SetCellValue("PCard Dt");
```

Now, I want to replace the hard-coded string "PCard Dt" with `[Display(Name = "From Date")]`.

I tried various answers on Google, but it's not serving my purpose.

Comment: Would be great if you can attach your existing code for the attempt. From my perspective, you need Reflection to iterate the properties in the class and retrieve the `DisplayAttribute` info applied to the property.

Comment: I have edited my question to include a code, please refer it, hope this will help

Answer (score 2):

The key point mentioned in the comment is you need *System.Reflection* to extract the `DisplayAttribute`.

Implement an extension method to extract the value from `DisplayAttribute`.

```cs
public static class ReflectionExtensions
{
    public static string ToName(this PropertyInfo propertyInfo)
    {
        try
        {
            object[] attributes = propertyInfo.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(DisplayAttribute), false);
                
            if (attributes != null && attributes.Any())
                return ((DisplayAttribute)attributes[0]).Name;

            return propertyInfo.Name;
        }
        catch
        {
            return propertyInfo.Name;
        }
    }
}
```

I wrote a similar implementation in [GitHub](https://github.com/yongshun950824/KYS.Library/blob/8ed8be407f3bc6b2751b3e3bfefa5200a94aedd5/KYS.Library/Extensions/ReflectionExtensions.cs#L12-L38).

With the below way to iterate all properties in class and get the value of `DisplayAttribute`.

> Caller

```cs
PropertyInfo[] props = typeof(Model).GetProperties(BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.GetProperty);

foreach (PropertyInfo prop in props)
{
    string displayName = prop.ToName();
}
```

---

Another approach to work with *System.Linq.Expression*.

```cs
public static class ReflectionExtensions
{
    public static string ToNameByExpression<T, P>(Expression<Func<T, P>> propertyExpression) where T : new ()
    {
        MemberExpression expression = propertyExpression.Body as MemberExpression;
        if (expression == null)
            return null;
                        
        return (expression.Member as PropertyInfo)
            .ToName();
    }
}
```

Provide the expression to specify the property that you want.

> Caller

```cs
string displayName = ReflectionExtensions.ToNameByExpression((Model m) => m.FromDate);
```

[Demo @ .NET Fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/7qV1do)

Answer (score 0):

You get display name attribute by this way:

```cs
public class TestModel
{
    [DisplayName("From Date")]
    public string FromDate { get; set; }
}

//generic method to get name
 private string GetDisplayName<T>(string propertyName)
    {
        MemberInfo property = typeof(T).GetProperty(propertyName);

        var attribute = property.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(DisplayNameAttribute), true)
            .Cast<DisplayNameAttribute>().FirstOrDefault();

        return attribute?.DisplayName ?? propertyName;
    }

//get display name
var displayName = GetDisplayName<TestModel>(nameof(TestModel.FromDate));
```